# rdblif pymongo, query on graph sometimes gives me error

Tags: flask, pymongo, sparql, rdflib

I'm using mongodb to store my json-ld files and i retrieve the information  i want with sparql queries.

```
@app.route('/api/ConceptVideoData/<video_id>/<concept_searched>')
@auth.login_required
def ConceptVideoData(video_id, concept_searched):
    user = "test"
    password = "test"
    #pymongo db config for query sparql
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
            "mongodb+srv://"+user+":"+password+"@test.test.mongodb.net/edurell?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    dbsparql = client.edurell
    # retrieve from mongodb collection=graphs the all elements with the value of video_id
    collection = dbsparql.graphs

    

    # initialize the dicitonary where we save our results
    result = {
        'video_id':video_id,
        'concept_starttime':[],
        'concept_endtime':[],
        'explain':[],
        'list_preconcept': [],
        'list_prenotes':[],
        'list_postnotes':[],
        'list_derivatedconcept':[],
        'derivatedconcept_starttime':[],
        'derivatedconcept_endtime':[]
        
    }
   
    cursor = collection.find({"video_id":video_id})
   
    gr=Graph()
    

   
   
       
        for idx,document in enumerate(cursor):
      
            if document["graph"]=="":
                continue
            if document["conceptVocabulary"] == "":
                continue
            gr.parse(data=json.dumps(document["graph"]), format='json-ld')

            
            gr.parse(data=json.dumps(document["conceptVocabulary"]), format='json-ld')
        


    qr = """
                PREFIX oa: test
                PREFIX edu: test
                PREFIX dctypes: test
                PREFIX dcterms: test
                PREFIX skos: test

                SELECT DISTINCT ?created
                WHERE{
                        ?who oa:motivatedBy oa:describing.
                        ?who dcterms:created ?created.
                        ?who a oa:Annotation.
                        ?who oa:hasBody ?c_id.
                        ?c_id skos:prefLabel ?c_selected.
                }
    """
 
    qres = gr.query(qr, initBindings = {"c_selected":Literal(concept_searched, lang="en")})
```

As you can see i call this api from React, to my main.py python file that handle the query. I start with connect to the db, then initialize my data structure **result** and then looking into the collection inside mongodb for multiple instances of the same data and here i saved the array inside cursor.

For each element in cursor i graph().parse it so i have a graph with all the stuff merged together. For some other stuff, sometimes the value "graph" or "conceptVocabulary" is missing so i just skip them.

then im ready to do my first query but after i call gr.query() it returns an error. The problem is that i just need to restart the flask server again and again till it will works. If it starts to make problem again, i just restart it. It's like when you hit that old TV till the screen will display the movie again correctly.

The errors i get are basically two and sometimes appears that and sometimes the other.

This one states something about TokenList

```
typeerror: postparse2 missing 1 required position argument tokenlist
```

Or about a terms

```
File "/home/mosenco/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 291, in wrapper

    ret = func(*args[limit:])

TypeError: expandTriples() missing 1 required positional argument: 'terms'
```

And some other times something about `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

that right now it doesnt appears. But to write down this post, i restarted 3 times? the flask server and at the forth, the query went through and i got my result correctly. But sometimes it wont and return those errors.

Ive noticed that the errors wont change until i restart the server. Its a local server in localhost.

Comment: This question reference the use of RDFLib but the way RDFLib works isn't discussed here, so the RDFLib tag should be removed.

Comment: Also: a very bad idea to store JSON-LD in Mondo and then de-serialise it into graphs. Try storing the JSON-LD as Named Graphs within an RDF DB like Fuseki and then pulling the graphs out using the Graph Store Protocol with further manipulation in RDFLib, as needed.